# Difference by month (dplyr, R)

Tags: r, dplyr, character, apply, lag

Let's say I have a data set looking below. The text repeats 'a' to 'e' having value for each month. It lasts from 2016 Jan to 2016 March.

```
date    text    value
1-16    a       13
1-16    b       2
1-16    c       3
1-16    d       1
1-16    e       20
2-16    a       30
2-16    b       50
2-16    c       20
2-16    d       10
2-16    e       40
3-16    a       34
3-16    b       3
3-16    c       2
3-16    d       1
3-16    e       4
```

I want to make a column having value of difference by month and by the text. What I mean is, 17 = (30(a, 2-16) - 13(a, 1-16)) like this,

```
date    text    value       the value that I want to have
1-16    a       13          na  
1-16    b       2           na  
1-16    c       3           na  
1-16    d       1           na  
1-16    e       20          na  
2-16    a       30  =(value(a, 2016-feb) - value(a, 2016-jan))  17
2-16    b       50  =(value(b, 2016-feb) - value(b, 2016-jan))  48
2-16    c       20  =(value(c, 2016-feb) - value(c, 2016-jan))  17
2-16    d       10  =(value(d, 2016-feb) - value(d, 2016-jan))  9
2-16    e       40  =(value(e, 2016-feb) - value(e, 2016-jan))  20
3-16    a       34  =(value(a, 2016-mar) - value(a, 2016-feb))  4
3-16    b       3   =(value(b, 2016-mar) - value(b, 2016-feb))  -47
3-16    c       2   =(value(c, 2016-mar) - value(c, 2016-feb))  -18
3-16    d       1   =(value(d, 2016-mar) - value(d, 2016-feb))  -9
3-16    e       4   =(value(e, 2016-mar) - value(e, 2016-feb))  -36
```

I made the data above. The actual data is longer and even more complex as it contains approximately 2000 text for each month and the data is not even in date. (It's also divided by many categories). So some solutions that calculate the value manually would not work.

I tried with dplyr lag, for example,

```
df %>% group_by(date, text) %>%
arrange(date, text) %>%
mutate(diff = value - lag(value))
```

but it did not work. I assume the code did not recognise text well?

What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or completely in R base using `ave`

```
> df$newVal <- ave(df$value, df$text,  FUN=function(x) c(NA,diff(x)))
> df
   date text value newVal
1  1-16    a    13     NA
2  1-16    b     2     NA
3  1-16    c     3     NA
4  1-16    d     1     NA
5  1-16    e    20     NA
6  2-16    a    30     17
7  2-16    b    50     48
8  2-16    c    20     17
9  2-16    d    10      9
10 2-16    e    40     20
11 3-16    a    34      4
12 3-16    b     3    -47
13 3-16    c     2    -18
14 3-16    d     1     -9
15 3-16    e     4    -36
```

with `aggregate`

```
df$newval <- c(aggregate(value ~ text, data=df, FUN=function(x) c(NA,diff(x)))[,-1])
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tired as you suggested and it seemed working! but as I have huge data set I need to ask if it would be sure the difference is calculated by month? maybe this is how ave works?

Comment: One more thing to ask, could you give me some advice how to apply this to many groups which share the same structure in a dataset? I'm concerned if the difference is mixed between groups, which is the problem that can be fixed with group_by if dplyr is used.

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`...

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(text) %>% mutate(newval=c(NA,diff(value)))

   date  text  value newval
   <chr> <chr> <int>  <int>
 1 1-16  a        13     NA
 2 1-16  b         2     NA
 3 1-16  c         3     NA
 4 1-16  d         1     NA
 5 1-16  e        20     NA
 6 2-16  a        30     17
 7 2-16  b        50     48
 8 2-16  c        20     17
 9 2-16  d        10      9
10 2-16  e        40     20
11 3-16  a        34      4
12 3-16  b         3    -47
13 3-16  c         2    -18
14 3-16  d         1     -9
15 3-16  e         4    -36
```

Comment: or completely in dplyr syntax: `df %>% group_by(text) %>%
  mutate(diff = value - lag(value))`. But +1 for diff

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did as you suggested with diff and lag. But it did not work making a new column containing only NA.

I assume the text may not be matched well? The example above looks quite simple but actual data includes lots of texts and I assume the value (lag or diff) cannot be calculated as those texts are not matched.

Comment: If it is the case, could you give me some advice?

Comment: Make sure your `value` column is numeric - `df$value <- as.numeric(df$value)` - if not, that would cause either of these methods to produce `NA`s

Comment: It is set as numeric. But diff as well as lag still produce NA only. When I tried some basic calculation such as +100, then it worked fine. Any other idea why it happened?

Comment: @Sue, Make sure your group_by contains the column text and not both date and text.